# How can I set the physical button to act as right click on an older MacBook?

Tags: release-loki, hardware

In Freya (and OS X), I could rest 2 fingers on the track pad and click the mouse button to right-click. (I have a 2008 MacBookPro with the actual physical button on the trackpad).

After the upgrade to Loki, I can't right click! I've tried both the previously mentioned two-finger click AND holding Command-Click. Neither works!

If I turn on touch gestures in System Settings, the two-finger tap definitely works, but I seem to have broken it while trying to configure a custom xorg.conf file for the synaptics driver.

Answer (score 3):

elementary OS Loki uses a new input stack called LibInput, so previous methods of configuring the trackpad through the command line or config files may not work.

By default, Loki should detect the right method of secondary-clicking according to your hardware. If you'd like to change it, visit **System Settings** > **Mouse & Touchpad** and choose an option under **Physical Clicking**.

Comment: So close. This is how I got the "two-finger tap" to right click on the trackpad. BUT. I have an actual physical mouse button. I should be able to rest 2 fingers on the trackpad and click it to Right-Click. Doing that only gives me a standard Left-Click. 
Essentially, how can I use my mouse button to Right Click? Even holding Command while clicking does nothing....

Comment: Is the whole trackpad a physical button? If so, that's what the Physical Clicking button should set; that's how it works on my Galago UltraPro and the MacBook Air, at least.

Comment: No I have the 2008 MBP. It still has a separate button and trackpad. I've tried pretty much every combination of settings in the normal Settings program, and nothing is working. 
I'm assuming that there is some kind of updated or legacy driver I can load, or a Synaptics setting that is not in the GUI?