# Elementary os Loki touchpad right-click

Tags: release-loki, touchpad

I installed elementary os loki in my old macbook (white one 2007 I think) everything is ok and working fine except touchpad right-click.

I tried with elementary s tweak, and touchpad configuration in system panel and editing /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf but nothing works.

Anybody could help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does any of this help? http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/7974/macbookpro-no-right-click

Comment: Thanks for the help! but the tip don't work. I read it and tried it previously to ask here and not worked.

In other hand the user of the link was talking about Macbook pro 2008 is a different touchpad technology.

I tried again with all posibilities: Multitouch, touchpad areas,... and still not working

Any ideas??

Thank in advance

Comment: Can you post the output of `xinput` and after you have found the `ID` of your touchpad, `xinput list-props ID` as well?